# Passing textBox to function. c++

Tags: c++, .net, managed-c++

```
#include "MyForm.h"
void showvec(System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ &textBox)
{
    textBox->Text = "";
}`
```

The problem is: I can't pass `textBox1->text` to this function. Furthermore it's seems that I can't even create a pointer to `textBox1->text`. Visual Studio compiled function but I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

The function code is:

```
void showvec(System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox)
{
    textBox->Text = "hgghjg";
}
```

and the call is:

```
showvec(textBox1);
```

I got this answer somewhere else. I hope it will help someone.